# jquery livevalidation

Tags: jquery, livevalidation

I'm using a script called livevalidation (http://livevalidation.com/) and here is my coding for this specific ID:

```
var First_Name = new LiveValidation( 'First_Name');
First_Name.add(Validate.Presence ); --this means it must have a value
First_Name.add(Validate.Format, { pattern: /^[a-z]+$/i} ); --this means it must be letters only
```

if it doesnt have a value invalid then wont submit now i want repetitive characters to make is become invalid as well like say if some one click the same letter times in the name then it will become invalid

```
Format: function(value, paramsObj){
  var value = String(value);
  var paramsObj = paramsObj || {};
  var message = paramsObj.failureMessage || "Not valid!";
  var pattern = paramsObj.pattern || /./;
  var negate = paramsObj.negate || false;
  if(!negate && !pattern.test(value)) Validate.fail(message); // normal
  if(negate && pattern.test(value)) Validate.fail(message); // negated
  return true;
},
```

your coding works but how do i put the coding in this format i want it to output a message when its invalid

Comment: I don't really understand what is your question... You have some validator on the fied `First_Name` and you want to add a new condition? And this condition is that this first name should not be constituted by a single letter (possibly repeated).

Comment: yeah basically if some one types like aaaa or bbbbjquery or livecccc etc then it will be invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom validation:

```
//Define function to check input values
var noRepeatativeChars = function(val) {
   val = val || ""; //Handle null and undefined.
   var chars = val.split(""),  //Convert string to char array
       len = chars.length - 1, i = 0;

   for(; i < len; i++) {
      if(chars[i] === chars[i+1]) { //If current char === next char.
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
};

//Add custom validator.
First_Name.add(Validate.Custom, {against: noRepeatativeChars, failureMessage: "Go read the manual!"});
```

Comment: could you explain the coding please

Comment: i edited a bit to fit my needs but how did you know exactly what to do

Comment: Hmm, 'how do I know exactly what to do'? I'd say telepathy :).

Comment: Format: function(value, paramsObj){
      var value = String(value);
      var paramsObj = paramsObj || {};
      var message = paramsObj.failureMessage || "Not valid!";
      var pattern = paramsObj.pattern || /./;
      var negate = paramsObj.negate || false;
      if(!negate && !pattern.test(value)) Validate.fail(message); // normal
      if(negate && pattern.test(value)) Validate.fail(message); // negated
      return true;
    },

Comment: What's this? I'm pretty sure you can't check input value for repeatative chars with regexp.

Comment: @ShayaaDobson: you need to add failureMessage param. I'd recommend you to read http://livevalidation.com/documentation